# jest.spyOn function which will be called after returning the result

Tags: jestjs

Consider we have class with some methods. We want to spyOn whether method B  is called or not whereas once executing the methodA will return result to the caller and methodB will executed asynchronously. The class looks like below.

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.conf = [{ id:'1', func: Parent.methodA.bind(Parent)}, { id:'2', func: Parent.methodB.bind(Parent)}]
    }
    static methodA() {
        console.log('methodA is called from methodC');
        return 'methodA';
    }
    static methodB() {
        console.log('methodB is called from methodC');
        return 'methodB';
    }
    methodC(conf) {
        conf.forEach((eachConf) => {
            if(eachConf.id === '1') {
                setImmediate(() => {
                    // Just to call method with conf = [{ id:'2', func: this.methodB.bind(this)}]
                    this.methodC(conf.slice(1));
                })
                return eachConf.func();
            }
            return eachConf.func();
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Parent;
```

In the jest test file, calling methodC and want to ensure methodA with return value and want to ensure methodB also get called.
testSpy.js
const Parent = require('./parent');

```
it('check methodA and methodB called', async () => {
    const methodA = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodA');
    const methodB = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodB');
    const instance = new Parent();
    instance.methodC(instance.conf);
    expect(methodA).toHaveBeenCalled();
    //How to spyOn methodB.
    //expect(methodB).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

There can be several methods to be run after returning the result. Want to ensure all of them was executed, and it would be better to get the result of each step too.

Answer (score 1):

`.bind` [creates a new function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) so `func` is set to the new function created by `this.methodA.bind(this)`.

When `jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodA');` runs it replaces `methodA` with a spy, but that doesn't have any effect on `func`.

When `func` gets called the new function is called and the spy on `methodA` never gets called.

---

You have to make sure the `spy` gets called if you want to use it to verify that `methodA` was called.

In this case instead of binding `methodA` to `this` using `bind` (which creates a new function), you can call `this.methodA` from within an arrow function (since arrow functions [capture the `this` of the enclosing lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)...in this case, the `this` from the constructor):

```js
constructor() {
  this.conf = [
    {
      id: '1',
      func: (...args) => this.methodA(...args)
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      func: (...args) => this.methodB(...args)
    }
  ];
}
```

Then when `func` is called it calls `methodA` which will call the `spy` and the test will pass.

---

**Update**

Here is a working test for your updated code sample:

```js
it('check methodA and methodB called', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const methodA = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodA');
  const methodB = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodB');
  const instance = new Parent();
  instance.methodC(instance.conf);
  jest.runAllTimers();
  expect(methodA).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // SUCCESS
  expect(methodB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);  // SUCCESS
});
```

`jest.useFakeTimers` replaces timer functions like `setImmediate` with mocks that remember what they were called with.  Then `jest.runAllTimers` runs all the callbacks scheduled with timer functions.

`methodA` gets called the first time `methodC` gets called.

`methodB` gets called the first time `methodC` gets called, and also gets called when `methodC` gets called again as a result of the `setImmediate` callback.

Comment: Yep thanks. To spyon the functions I defined in a different way which worked. But my question here is how do we spyOn some functions which run asynchronously after I return.  Note: To run function asynchronously I am using setImmediate here.

Comment: @jerry Please update your question with the new code and I will update my answer with how to test the asynchronous call.  (Note that the code from your question never actually calls `methodB`)

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors.Updated the question

Comment: @jerry are you trying to test that `methodB` gets called?  ...because your code doesn't call `methodB`.  The entry for `methodB` in `this.conf` has an `id` of `2` and your `if` statement is only running for an `id` of `1` so only `methodA` ever gets called.

Comment: Yep now updated. As it is sample code, I missed that

Comment: @jerry  I updated my answer with a working test and explanation

Answer (score 0):

As you use `setImmediate` you need to use [`jest.useFakeTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestusefaketimers) and [`jest.runAllTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrunalltimers) to invoke every callback you put into `setImmediate` immediately.

```
it('check methodA and methodB called', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    const methodA = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodA');
    const methodB = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodB');
    Parent.methodC(Parent.conf);
    jest.runAllTimers()
    expect(methodA).toHaveBeenCalled();
    //How to spyOn methodB.
    //expect(methodB).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Even with jestUseFakeTimers() & jest.runAllTimers(), couldn't spyOn all the function getting executed after return. If I have more than one function running after the return statement, it spyOn very first function. Not for all.